# Javascript match regex behaviour

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm learning about the match operator in Javascript, capture groups, etc. But I'm struggling to understand how the following works.

```
var string = 'string of random words';
var match = string.match(/((random)|(words))/);
// returns array of 4 elements
0: "random"
1: "random"
2: "random"
3: undefined
```

I'm struggling to work this out. I can see that there is a pipe character, and that would mean match either the string 'random' or 'words'. I can see random and words are in parentheses, so this is a capture group, and there are parentheses around the whole expression.

Can somebody help?

```js
var string = 'string of random words';
var match = string.match(/((random)|(words))/);
console.log(match)
```

Comment: The resource I use to test and debug regular expressions is Regex101. Here is your example explained: https://regex101.com/r/DZfgCU/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (`[0]`th) element of a RegExp match array is the entire match.

Parentheses `(` which don't start with `(?:` denote capture groups. (`(?:` denotes a non-capturing group)

The second (`[1]`) element is the first capture group. If the group wasn't matched at all (for example, `'foo'.match('(z)|(f)')`), it will contain `undefined`.

The other indicies of the match array behave the same way - the `[2]` element corresponds to the second capture group, and the `[3]`rd element corresponds to the third capture group, and so on.

The match array will contain elements equal to the number of capture groups in the expression, plus one (for the full match at position 0).

Here, what's happening is:

- Full match is `random`
- First capture group encompasses the whole match - same as full match, `random`
- Second capture group, inside first capture group, but happens to consume all characters as well: `random`
- Third capture group, inside first capture group: not matched (because it's on the right-hand side of a `|` when the regex matched only the left side): contains `undefined`

```
/((random)|(words))/
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ First capture group (matched, contains "random")
/((random)|(words))/
   ^^^^^^           Second capture group (matched, contains "random")
/((random)|(words))/
            ^^^^^ Third capture group (not matched this time, so undefined)
```

If you're new to regex match arrays, it would be much easier to understand by starting out by seeing what happens when the groups don't all contain the same text:

```js
var string = 'abcdef';
var match = string.match(/ab(c(de)|(zzz))/);
console.log(match)
```

```
ab(c(de)|(zzz))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Full match (abcde)
ab(c(de)|(zzz))
   ^^^^^^^^^^^ First capture group (cde)
ab(c(de)|(zzz))
     ^^        Second capture group (de)
ab(c(de)|(zzz))
          ^^^  Third capture group (not matched, so undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not matching `words` because your regex is missing the global flag `g`. This flag tells the regex not to stop after the first match. If you add this flag to your regex, you'll match both random and words.

```js
var string = 'string of random words';
var match = string.match(/((random)|(words))/g);
console.log(match)
```

here is a more indept explanation on what your regex does.
[image: Regular expression visualization]

If you are every struggling with regex, i suggest using site like [regex101](https://regex101.com/), it really helps understanding correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. First entry: between `/     /` what you are specifying to match, for the requirement that it is either `random` or `words`, it can be matched and it is `random`
2. Second entry:
   the first opening `(` to the matching `)`, the match is    `random`
3. Third entry:  the second opening `(` to the matching `)`, the match
   is `random`
4. Fourth entry:  the third opening `(` to the matching
   `)`, there is nothing matched.

Why is the fourth entry not matched? Because it tried to get a piece of content in the string that satisfy your "random or words" requirement, and at the `r` of `random`, the regex part of `random` can be matched, but `words` cannot, so the 3rd capture group is undefined.

If you specify [the `g` flag or modifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If the g flag is used, **all results** matching the complete regular expression will be returned, but capturing groups will not.

```js
console.log('string of random words'.match(/((random)|(words))/g));
```

It goes like this: starting at the `s` of `string`, can it match your regular expression of "random or words"? It cannot. Then moving 1 character to the right, can it match "random or words"? No, ... and so on. At the `r` of `random`, it can match your regex, and then at the space after `random`, can it match your regex? No. One character over to the right, it can... and so forth. That's why "all results" are `["random", "words"]`.

So you can keep on scanning all the matches, again and again, but the downside is that you don't have access to the capture groups.

So what if you want [to be able to scan all the matches, but also want the capture groups? Then you can use `matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```js
console.log([...'string of random words'.matchAll(/((random)|(words))/g)]);
```

You can see that at the `w` of `words`, it matched the `words` part of your regex, and the second capture group of `random` is not matched.